# How to extract a substring from file in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have file which is generating each time and each time id in bold is getting change.

temp.text

|auger_5d_multivt_relative|**5e2fea0ffe0490769c682c13**|  5DM|     |      |  INALEC|
                                    nightly_inalec|
|auger_dis|**5e2fea151a4cc938e465d8f2**|   3D|   |                        |  INALEC|
                                    nightly_inalec|

I want to extract only bold string.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your file is called test.txt, launch this command

```
cat test.txt | cut -f3 -d\|
```

Explanation:
The cut command filters a text cutting fields, delimited by a given separator

```
-f3 -->  the third parameter
-d\| --->  with | as delimiter
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk

```
awk -F'|' '{print $3}' log.txt
```